# How to make pdf and content searchable again in Onenote

Tags: pdf, search, microsoft-onenote, ocr, handwriting

A year ago, I could use the search option in every OneNote documents very efficiently (to be more precise I'm using "OneNote for Windows 10" (software version)), it would find words in pdf's I inserted, even recognizing words in my (ugly) handwriting.

Oddly, this very useful function stopped working a few months ago. Now, it cannot find anything else than keyboard typed words (kind of useless since I mostly don't have them in my documents).

I have all my lectures (thousands of pages …) in OneNote and it is getting really inconvenient. When searching for a topic, I have to open pdf's separately in adobe, then make a search, then get back to OneNote and scroll down until I find the corresponding annotated page.

Also I can't make a search directly on a folder of documents anymore (something I was using constantly before because frequently I'm not 100% sure in which document the information I'm searching for is) and I can't search handwritten words at all anymore (that part isn't the most important though, I would already be happy to find a solution for the previous points).

Does anybody knows why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to use OneNote for Windows 10, but to use the "full" version of [OneNote](https://www.onenote.com/download).

OneNote for Windows 10 is a very cut-down version of OneNote. It has a better synchronisation engine and a marginally cleaner interface than the normal OneNote version, but it lacks a lot of features. One of those features being image to text conversion.

"OneNote for Windows 10" [has also been discontinued](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/making-it-easier-to-get-to-the-onenote-app-on-windows/ba-p/3642219) in favour of "OneNote from Microsoft 365" which is the new "old" version of OneNote which has been [repackaged to go on the Windows Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/onenote/XPFFZHVGQWWLHB).

If you have Microsoft 365  with Word and Excel then you may already have the full version of OneNote installed and not need the Store version at all.

Comment: Thank you ! I basically wasn't a fan of that version of OneNote, but since they made some effort in refreshing it, I'll give it a go !